# How to send "Ctrl + End" in Sikuli?

Tags: sikuli

I am new to Sikuli and would appreciate if some can tell me how to do How to send "Ctrl + End" in Sikuli?

```
Screen screen = new Screen();
screen.type(Key.CTRL + Key.END);
```

Comment: What's wrong with that you have typed? It doesn't work? Need more details here.

Comment: Hi Eugene,
 
It's a mainframe screen data. We need to delete the whole text from the screen. Tried the above key and many more scenarios but it didn't work.
 
Appreciate your help and support.